# return the maximum value in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, return-value

I had an an assignment with this question

Write a function maxArray which receives an array of double's and returns the maximum value in the array. using this function

```
double maxArray(double dar[], int size);
```

---

I did what he want and I had problem with the calling sentence within the main method !!

here is my code :

```
public class Q3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double dar[] = { 22.5 , 10.23 , 15.04 , 20.77 };
        double max = maxArray(dar,4);
        System.out.println("the largest number is : " + max);
    }

    double maxArray(double dar[], int size) {
        double maxV = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dar.length; i++) {
            if (dar[i] > maxV ) {         
                maxV = dar[i];          
            }
        }
        return maxV;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't call your method from `main()` is that `main()` is `static` whereas your method isn't.

Change it to:

```
static double maxArray(double dar[], int size)
```

While you're at it, remove `size` since it's not necessary.

It is probably also worth noting that your method would fail if the array were to contain negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

your **maxArray** method is a **non static** method. you cannot access non-static methods from static methods without an instance of the class, you should create an instance of your class and call maxArray method

```
double max = new Q3().maxArray(dar,4);
```

Or alternatively, you could always mark your maxArray method static and call it directly from main method.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `maxArray` as `static`, so you can access it as from a static method `main()`

or

You create an instance of your class and call it from the object.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is you are trying to call maxArray, a non-static method, from your main method, which is static. That's a problem because a non-static method can only be called from an instance of the class, whereas a static method is called via the class itself.

Either make your maxArray a static method, or initialize a Q3 object in your main method, and call maxArray like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your method has to be static, so you have to say

```
static double maxArray(double dar[], int size)
```

Here are some hints how you could improve your method:
since you don't use the value "size" once, you can either throw it out or replace the `i < dar.length` with `i < size`.

Also, when initializing `maxV` in the maxArray method, you might want to use the first value of the array (`double maxV = dar[0]`), because if all doubles in the array are negative, maxV with the number 0 will be the highest. (You could also use the lowest double value possible by saying `double maxV = Double.MIN_NORMAL`).

Answer (score 0):

1) make your method static
2) Remember in java use BigDecimal class to do any decimal arithmetic.